# WSSF Alternative

Tags: c#-4.0, wssf

Microsoft has just retired Web Service Software Factory (WSSF) which is used to generate code for WCF and ASMX services. Microsoft doesn't intend to update this product any more.
I hope there must be an alternative but I don't know. I just want to know that what is the alternative which Microsoft will provide for this tool?
Can anyone Help me in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSSF is being retired by Microsoft, however it will still be supported by the [Open WSSF Community project on CodePlex](http://servicefactory.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks to Reply. I know what you pointed out but I want to know What is the Next?

Comment: The Replacement of WSSF Which Microsoft will provide.

Comment: WCF Data Services does a part of this. Beyond that only the information Microsoft leaks can tell.

Comment: I'm currently working on an announcement that will provide an update on the future of all of the Software Factories from p&p, and what the roadmap is going forward. WRT WSSF, there won't be another version from Microsoft, but Digit Factory, the company sponsoring the open source version of WSSF helped us build every version of WSSF and knows the code better than anyone. They are intending to maintain it. There is also some technology on the near horizon that will make it very easy to build a new (much better) WSSF. All of this will be in the announcement.